# How to properly set information to ArrayList TextView that is being inflated from a single List Item?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I apologize in advance for the potentially confusing title, I'm not exactly sure how to phrase the question, but I'll try to clearly explain what my issue is...

My issue arises when I'm trying to set the text of the TextViews to display the individual distances. I'm using a single TextView in a list_item.xml which my Custom ArrayAdapter then inflates and populates the ListView (word_list.xml) with.

I've tried many methods, but I've only "succeeded" with one specific method - it only ended up populating the first list item with the data, but not the rest of them.

My prime issue is with **`mFormattedDistanceString`** (found at the very bottom of the ListView Activity I've copied here). It is the variable in which all my calculated location distance information resides. I can't seem to get it to set to the TextViews within the ArrayList. I feel like the answer might be simple, but I just can't seem to think straight with it - I've tried many different options that I've researched, to no avail.

**Custom Data Type for ArrayAdapter.**

```
public class Word {

private String mName;

private int mImageResourceId = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;

private double mDistanceLat;

private double mDistanceLong;

private String mLocationData;

private static final int NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED = -1;

public Word(String name) {
    mName = name;
}

public Word(String name, int imageResourceId) {
    mName = name;
    mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
}

public Word(String name, int imageResourceId, double distanceLat, double distanceLong,
            String locationData){
    mName = name;
    mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    mDistanceLat = distanceLat;
    mDistanceLong = distanceLong;
    mLocationData = locationData;
}

public Word(int imageResourceId) {
    mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public int getImageResourceId() {
    return mImageResourceId;
}

public double getDistanceLat() {
    return mDistanceLat;
}

public double getDistanceLong() {
    return mDistanceLong;
}

public String getLocationData() {
    return mLocationData;
}

public boolean hasImage() {
    return mImageResourceId != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
}
}
```

**Custom ArrayAdapter.**

I've researched for hours and even tried a few different methods within the getView method, but I couldn't get all my list-items to display the data, only the first element in the list.

```
public class LocationsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context mContext;
private Location mLocation;
private String mFormattedDistanceString;

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView image;
    TextView distanceText;
}

public LocationsAdapter(Activity context, List<Word> locations, String formattedDistanceString) {
    super(context, 0, locations);

    mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mFormattedDistanceString = formattedDistanceString;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image_view);
        viewHolder.distanceText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance_text_view);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.text.setText(currentWord.getName());
    viewHolder.distanceText.setText(currentWord.getLocationData());


    if (currentWord.hasImage())

    {
        viewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

**One of my ListView Activites.**

```
public class Locations extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 100;

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private static final String LOG_TAG = Locations.class.getName();

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private String mFormattedDistanceString;

    public List<Word> locations = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[],
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    private String simplifiedMilesDecimal(double miles) {
        DecimalFormat simplifiedDistance = new DecimalFormat("0.0 Miles Away");
        return simplifiedDistance.format(miles);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_list);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
        }

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        locations.add(new Word("Bristol", R.drawable.bristol,
                41.670374, -71.276565, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Warren", R.drawable.warren,
                41.729085, -71.282283, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Newport", R.drawable.newport_breakers,
                41.486677, -71.315144, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Jamestown", R.drawable.jamestown,
                41.496313, -71.368435, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Beavertail", R.drawable.beavertail,
                41.458054, -71.395744, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Providence", R.drawable.providence,
                41.830279, -71.414955, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Roger Williams Park", R.drawable.roger_williams_park,
                41.788673, -71.414179, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Colt State Park", R.drawable.colt_state_park,
                41.677248, -71.298871, mFormattedDistanceString));

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView, true);

        listView.setAdapter(new LocationsAdapter(this, locations, mFormattedDistanceString));

        // Set a click listener to open the default Maps app when the list item is clicked on
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.670374, -71.276565?z=15"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.729085, -71.282283?z=15"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.486677, -71.315144?z=13"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.496313, -71.368435?z=14"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 4) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.458054, -71.395744?z=14"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 5) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.830279, -71.414955?z=14"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 6) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.788673, -71.414179?z=16"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 7) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.677248, -71.298871?z=14"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        // If the user has stopped the app, disconnect from the GoogleApiClient.
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Location services connected.");

        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest, this);
        } else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " +
                    connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, location.toString());

        LatLng currentUserCoord = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        Word locationsListItem = locations.get(0);

        LatLng destinationCoord = new LatLng(locationsListItem.getDistanceLat(),
                locationsListItem.getDistanceLong());

        double distanceInMiles =
                LatLngTool.distance(currentUserCoord, destinationCoord, LengthUnit.MILE);

        String formattedDistance = simplifiedMilesDecimal(distanceInMiles);
        mFormattedDistanceString = toString().valueOf(formattedDistance);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, mFormattedDistanceString);
    }
}
```

I tried using a for-loop within the Locations Activity to iterate through the elements in the ArrayList, but I'm not sure if I set it up wrong or if it just isn't the right way to go about solving the problem.

Is the best way to go about it to somehow get the location data held within **`mFormattedDistanceString`** and pass it to the LocationsAdapter so that the **`getView`** method can do its thing and populate the ListView with the distance information, just like it already does with the ImageViews, etc?

Let me know if I'm wrong and what you think I should do!

**UPDATE**

Here are my blocks of code with the changes suggested by @cark so we can find the solution... I feel like it's something quite simple, but I can't figure it out - so many variables, references, and methods to keep track of... :(

**Word class.**

```
public class Word {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = Word.class.getName();

    private String mName;

    private int mImageResourceId = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;

    private double mDistanceLat;

    private double mDistanceLong;

    private Location currentLocation;

    private String mFormattedDistanceString;

    private String simplifiedMilesDecimal(double miles) {
        DecimalFormat simplifiedDistance = new DecimalFormat("0.0 Miles Away");
        return simplifiedDistance.format(miles);
    }

    public void updateDistance(Location location){
        if(location.equals(currentLocation)) return;

        LatLng currentUserCoord = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, toString().valueOf(currentUserCoord));

        LatLng destinationCoord = new LatLng(this.getDistanceLat(),
                this.getDistanceLong());

        double distanceInMiles =
                LatLngTool.distance(currentUserCoord, destinationCoord, LengthUnit.MILE);

        String formattedDistance = simplifiedMilesDecimal(distanceInMiles);
        mFormattedDistanceString = toString().valueOf(formattedDistance);

        currentLocation = location;
    }

    private static final int NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED = -1;

    public Word(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public Word(String name, int imageResourceId) {
        mName = name;
        mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }

    public Word(String name, int imageResourceId, double distanceLat, double distanceLong,
                String formattedDistanceString){
        mName = name;
        mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
        mDistanceLat = distanceLat;
        mDistanceLong = distanceLong;
        mFormattedDistanceString = formattedDistanceString;
    }

    public Word(String name, int imageResourceId, double distanceLat, double distanceLong){
        mName = name;
        mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
        mDistanceLat = distanceLat;
        mDistanceLong = distanceLong;
    }

    public Word(int imageResourceId) {
        mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public int getImageResourceId() {
        return mImageResourceId;
    }

    public double getDistanceLat() {
        return mDistanceLat;
    }

    public double getDistanceLong() {
        return mDistanceLong;
    }

    public String getFormattedDistance() {
        return mFormattedDistanceString;
    }

    public boolean hasImage() {
        return mImageResourceId != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
    }
}
```

**LocationsAdapter class.**

```
public class LocationsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private Location mLocation;

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView image;
        TextView distanceText;
    }

    public LocationsAdapter(Activity context, List<Word> locations, Location location) {
        super(context, 0, locations);

        mLocation = location;
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setCurrentLocation(Location lastLocation)
    {
        mLocation = lastLocation;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image_view);
            viewHolder.distanceText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance_text_view);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.text.setText(currentWord.getName());

        currentWord.updateDistance(mLocation);
        viewHolder.distanceText.setText(currentWord.getFormattedDistance());

        if (currentWord.hasImage())

        {

            viewHolder.image.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());

            viewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // Otherwise hide the ImageView (set visibility to GONE)
            viewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Locations Activity.**

```
public class Locations extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 100;

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private static final String LOG_TAG = Locations.class.getName();

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private String mFormattedDistanceString;

    Location mLocation = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    private ListView mListView;

    public List<Word> locations = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[],
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_list);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

            }
        }

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mFormattedDistanceString = new String();

        locations.add(new Word("Bristol", R.drawable.bristol,
                41.670374, -71.276565, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Warren", R.drawable.warren,
                41.729085, -71.282283, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Newport", R.drawable.newport_breakers,
                41.486677, -71.315144, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Jamestown", R.drawable.jamestown,
                41.496313, -71.368435, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Beavertail", R.drawable.beavertail,
                41.458054, -71.395744, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Providence", R.drawable.providence,
                41.830279, -71.414955, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Roger Williams Park", R.drawable.roger_williams_park,
                41.788673, -71.414179, mFormattedDistanceString));
        locations.add(new Word("Colt State Park", R.drawable.colt_state_park,
                41.677248, -71.298871, mFormattedDistanceString));

        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mListView, true);

        mListView.setAdapter(new LocationsAdapter(this, locations, mLocation));

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.670374, -71.276565?z=15"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.729085, -71.282283?z=15"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.486677, -71.315144?z=13"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.496313, -71.368435?z=14"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 4) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.458054, -71.395744?z=14"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 5) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.830279, -71.414955?z=14"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 6) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.788673, -71.414179?z=16"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } else if (position == 7) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:41.677248, -71.298871?z=14"));
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // If the app already has the permission to access the user's location at high accuracy
        // (fine location), then connect to the GoogleApiClient.
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        // If the user has stopped the app, disconnect from the GoogleApiClient.
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Location services connected.");

        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLocation == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest, this);
        } else {
            handleNewLocation(mLocation);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " +
                    connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        LocationsAdapter adapter = (LocationsAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();
        adapter.setCurrentLocation(location);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, location.toString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

- when the `onLocationChanged` is called, pass the Location to the LocationsAdapter (create the method `setCurrentLocation`).
- call `(LocationsAdapter)(listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();` 
  (listView has to become a class field)
- in the `getView` of your adapter calculate the distance and set the text to the textView.

In order to optimize the distance calculation you can store the value in the model, but remember to store the Location object as well. 
In this way you can check, in the future calls, if the Location object has changed. If the Location object changes you need to recalculate the distance, otherwise  you can show the last calculated distance.

---

**UPDATE**

Remove `private String mFormattedDistanceString;` from `LocationsAdapter`. You don't need this, and remove it from the constructor as well.

In your `LocationsAdapter` you have `mLocation`, but you never assign it. Add this method to `LocationsAdapter` to assign mLocation when it changes in your activity.
`public void setCurrentLocation(Location lastLocation){ mLocation = lastLocation}`

Make `listView` a field of `Locations` activity and change `onLocationChanged` in this way:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LocationsAdapter adapter = (LocationsAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
    adapter.setCurrentLocation(location);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

create this method in your `Word` class:

```
Location currentLocation;
public void updateDistance(Location location){
    if(location.equals(currentLocation)) return;
    //calculate the distance and create the distance string, and set it 
    //as a class field (you can call it mFormattedDistanceString)
    currentLocation = location;
}
```

In the `getView` of the adapter, call `updateDistance`, and than set the TextView text using `mFormattedDistanceString` of `Word`

Comment: Hello cark, thanks so much for your response! I apologize for being a pain, but could you possibly break your answer down a bit more for me? I'm still very new to Java and programming in general (been learning for just 3 months now) and while I get some of what you said, I'm not entirely sure how to implement those methods or where.

Comment: Hi cark, thanks so much for your clarification. If you don't mind, I do have a couple questions... Firstly, I copied over my distance calculation from where it initially resided, in the Locations Activity, to my Word class, per your instructions, however I realized that I was relying on the ArrayList created within the Activity to perform my calculations. "Word locationsListItem = locations.get(0);" Any idea what is to be done here so I could still perform that calculation? Finally, I can't seem to figure out how to call updateDistance from within the adapter, can you remind me?

Comment: In the Word class you don't need ""Word locationsListItem = locations.get(0);", you can use "this", because you are inside the word class.
Inside the getView method you can call "updateDistance" just before the setText:
currentWord.updateDistance(mLocation);
viewHolder.distanceText.setText(currentWord.getLocationData());

Comment: Hello cark, some reason the Location data doesn't seem to be passing into my Word class properly. I used Logcat to look at my LatLng "currentUserCoord" variable, and it shows that my coordinates are 0.0, 0.0 - so all the list-items have their distance calculated from the position of 0.0, 0.0, so the distances to the locations are shown as 5259.8 miles away, 5261,0 miles away, etc. ... Is there any way that the Location data wasn't passed into Word properly from the Locations Activity? Thanks for your continued help and advice!

Comment: Try to use Logcat before each location invocation, starting by the initial method: onLocationChanged. If you want some other help, publish the code, otherwise it's quite difficult for me ;)

Comment: Ok, I edited my main post with the new blocks of code. They start below the bold "UPDATE" text. :) If you want it to be quicker to read, I can cut out whatever code is not relevant to what needs to be solved. Just let me know.

Comment: It looks like I figured it out - using the Logcat method you mentioned!   I simply moved all the data from onLocationChanged() and put it into handleNewLocation(). I then called handeNewLocation() within onLocationChanged() - I think what actually fixed it was that onConnected() was calling handleNewLocation() when the data wasn't in there. But once I copied it in, suddenly everything appears to work! Did that make sense? :P

Comment: Yes, it sounds ok. Just a little note: the proper name for the method updateDistance should be updateDistanceIfNeeded, because it describes better what the method really does ;) Happy coding!

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks so much for your help! You're awesome :)